# Renombrar un fichero en Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-c++

Intento renombrar un fichero pero visual studio 2019
Me muestra
La operacion ha fallado con codigo 13
La operacion ha fallado con codigo Permission denied

esto es utilizando rename

```
const char oldname[] = "Aux_Archivo.txt";
const char newname[] = "Archivo.txt";

if (rename(oldname, newname))
{
    char buf[256];
    strerror_s(buf, 256, errno);
    std::cout << "La operacion ha fallado con codigo " << errno << '\n';
    std::cout << "La operacion ha fallado con codigo " << buf << '\n';

    system("pause");

    main();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por los consejos ya lo he intentado pero aun así me sigue dando el mismo error. Hay algo mas con lo que pueda intentar ?

Comment: @Trauma Tal vez tengas razón, estoy suponiendo que la persona tiene conocimiento de que está haciendo. Borré el comentario para evitar problemas.

Comment: Y tienes permiso para escribir en ese directorio? Te ocurre lo mismo si ejecutas el programa como administrador? Si te deja como administrador o te deja en otro directorio, ya sabes lo que es.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tengas el fichero abierto? O uno de los dos, si estás intentando sobreescribir "Archivo.txt". Si tienes el fichero abierto (incluso por el mismo proceso) Windows se niega a hacerle cambios.

Comment: aun cargandolo como administrador y moviendo la ruta sigue dando el mismo inconveniente @SuperG280 y e comprobado que si se cierra el fichero Archivo.txt incluso lo borro para estar seguro pero aun asi no logro que funcione que cambie el nombre del Aux_Archivo.txt

Comment: @SJuan76 gracias por indicarme la sugerencia revise linea por linea y efectivamente el fichero no estaba cerrado en una de sus operaciones muchas gracias por la ayuda